# Are Display Lists better then Immedient Mode when used once?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, rendering

**Disclamer: Due to the lack of documentation I can't use any newer version of OpenGL**

I'm wondering which is better to use, Display Lists that are only used once, or Immedient Mode in OpenGL.

Take this for example:

Example 1:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();
```

Example 2:

```
GLuint quad;
quad = glGenLists(1);
glNewList(quad, GL_COMPILE);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();

glEndList();
glCallList(quad);
```

If I did either example 1, or example 2 every update (which in the case of the Display Lists, the variable *cube* will have to be compiled again and give new vertices), which would be faster?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of display lists is to be *reused* to save the overhead of making all these calls. Building a DL and then immediately calling it, only to be discarded right after is insane. It will just increase the overhead for drawing a single thing.

That being said, you should not use either display lists nor immediate mode. Use vertex arrays and VBOs.

Comment: As the disclaimer said, I can't. The OpenGL headers nor other OpenGL tutorials specifically document the versions and versions of each header required.

Comment: @MonetR.Adams: Vertex Arrays are nothing particularily new. They're around since version 1.1 which is even supported by over 15 year old implementations.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your disclaimer doesn't make any sense - not to be patronizing, have you tried Googling this? Here's a [wiki page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification) on vertex specification. You can peruse the rest of the wiki to see which functions have been deprecated and when new ones have been added. For example, check out the page on [glBindBuffer()](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBindBuffer). To be fair, it *does* take a bit of effort to figure your way around all the OpenGL documentation out there - a number of tutorials are far out of date, and finding the right [PDF](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengl43-quick-reference-card.pdf)s and [other pages](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/) can be a task itself.
2. You should use the latest possible version of OpenGL - use VBOs and VAOs. They're far better than either display lists and immediate mode. Why argue between a Civic and a Beetle when you could be driving a Viper?
3. If you must know, the speed answer is: it depends on the OpenGL implementation. That display list is very small, so the overhead of your display list is probably higher than just doing it in immediate mode. Ye olde Red Book 1.1 [explains this whole concept](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter07.html) in detail.
4. You can try profiling your code to see which runs faster. This will give you the definitive answer on your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

> Due to the lack of documentation

Full opengl function reference for

1. [OpenGL 4](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/)
2. [OpenGL 3.3](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/)
3. [OpenGL 2](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/).

[Specifications and reference pages.](http://www.opengl.org/registry/)

[opengl.org (books, docs, etc)](http://www.opengl.org/)

[OpenGL extension wrangler library.](http://glew.sourceforge.net/)

There's no lack of documentation for OpenGL. You can find documentation for pretty much anything OpenGL-related.

> Display Lists that are only used once, or Immedient Mode in OpenGL.

Immediate mode. Display lists are supposed to be reused, if you use display list only once, rendering will only take longer (99.9% certainty).